# Como criar e implantar mascara para CPF, CNPJ, Data e Valores?

Tags: php, mask

Tentei seguir uns exemplos de mascaras mas eu não consegui integrar no meu código... alguém poderia me ajudar?

```
<table style="width: 100%" border="0">
    <thead>
        <tr style="text-align: left;">
            <th>Data</th> // Data ta retornando assim: 2019-03-28T00:00:00
            <th>Valores</th> // Valores esta retornando assim: 4688.86
            <th>CPF</th> // Mascara para CPF
            <th>CNPJ</th> // Mascara para CNPJ

        </tr>

    </thead>
<tbody>
<?php

    foreach ($json_data["Result"] as $data) {
    foreach ($data["CreditData"][0]["Occurrences"][0]["Details"] as $details) {

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' .$details["ExpiringDate"].'</td>'; // preciso da data 01/01/2019
        echo '<td> R$: ' .$details["Value"].'</td>'; // preciso do valor R$ 111.111.111,00
        echo '<td> R$: ' .$details["cpf"].'</td>'; //  Retornando CPF
        echo '<td> R$: ' .$details["cnpj"].'</td>'; // Retornando CNPJ
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}   
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

No caso do valor minha linha de retorno é:

```
// echo '<br>Valor Total em Ocorrencias: R$ ' .$data["CreditData"][0]["TotalDebts"]; 
echo number_format($data["CreditData"][0]["TotalDebts"], 2, ",", ".");
```

Mas não funcionou, a linha desabilitada funciona meu retorno R$ 111111111.00

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você precisa de três tipos de máscaras:

**CPF/CNPJ:**

```
function mask($val, $mask) {
    $maskared = '';
    $k = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i<=strlen($mask)-1; $i++) {
        if($mask[$i] == '#') {
            if(isset($val[$k])) $maskared .= $val[$k++];
        } else {
            if(isset($mask[$i])) $maskared .= $mask[$i];
        }
    }
    return $maskared;
}

$cpf = mask($details["cpf"], '###.###.###-##');
$cnpj = mask($details["cnpj"], '##.###.###/####-##');
```

**Dinheiro:**

```
number_format($details["Value"], 2, ",", ".");
```

**Data:**

```
$data = date('d/m/y', strtotime($details["ExpiringDate"]));
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer de uma forma mais simples:

```
$value = '12345678901000';

printf(
    '%d%d.%d%d%d.%d%d%d/%d%d%d-%d%d',
    ...str_split($value)
);

// 12.345.678/9010-00
```

Você só precisa garantir que o valor está completo. No caso do exemplo, `$value` precisa ter 14 caracteres para utilizar a máscara.

#### str_split

Converte uma string em uma *array*.

#### printf

A função `printf` do PHP formata a *string* no formato informado no parâmetro `$format`. Os demais parâmetros são recursivos, ou seja, cada um deles devem se referir à uma posição na *string*.

No meu exemplo (`%d%d.%d%d%d.%d%d%d/%d%d%d-%d%d`), cada `%d` indica que você deseja adicionar um número na posição.
Sendo assim, você precisa informar 14 caracteres numéricos nos parâmetros.

**No *snippet* passei apenas um pois usei o *spread operator* `...`.**

##### PS

Se precisar utilizar o valor como retorno de uma função, utilize o `sprintf` no lugar do `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

Para a data, você pode usar esse código `date('d/m/Y', strtotime('2019-03-28T00:00:00'));`, caso a data esteja chegando para você com string.

Acredito que esse link vai te ajudar a montar os valores numéricos que você precisa: [Máscaras em PHP](http://blog.clares.com.br/php-mascara-cnpj-cpf-data-e-qualquer-outra-coisa/)

Comment: Gabriel Roberto.. valeu a dica.... Data e Hora consegui colocar a Mascara.... mas para o valor não conseguir... eu editei minha pergunta para o amigo visualizar como é minha linha de retorno do valor...

Comment: @MarcosRS,  verifica qual é o tipo do valor que está sendo retornado, talvez seja necessário converter o valor para float, caso ele seja uma string, pra isso você pode usar a função floatval()

Comment: Gabriel, consegui... deu certo .. me diz uma coisa e para colocar mascara em CEP e telefone? tem um exemplo...diferente do exemplo do site que o amigo indicou, ou posso seguir a mesma logica do CPF? $cep = mask($details["cep"], '#####.###');

Comment: Pode seguir a mesma lógica do cpf mesmo, é bom que você já tem a função pronta.

Answer (score 0):

Eu tenho uma situação que o CPF/CNPJ pode ser parcialmente mascarado, por exemplo `058705.310-04` ou `20233854/0001-25`

Então fiz uma modificação da resposta do @dm707 para pular em situações que já tem o caractere da mascara.

Vou compartilhar para o caso de alguém que ter o mesmo cenário que o meu.

```php
function mask($val, $mask) {
    $maskared = '';
    $k = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i<=strlen($mask)-1; $i++) {
        if($mask[$i] == '#') {
            if(isset($val[$k])) $maskared .= $val[$k++];
        } else {
            if(isset($mask[$i])) {
                if($mask[$i] == $val[$k]) {
                    $k++;
                }
                $maskared .= $mask[$i];
             }
        }
    }
    return $maskared;
}

$cpf = mask($details["cpf"], '###.###.###-##');
$cnpj = mask($details["cnpj"], '##.###.###/####-##');
```